# Unable to load UITableView in Playground

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift-playground

I'm trying to add a `UITableView` in a Swift playground but for some reason it is not loading. Here is my code:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    let content = ["One", "Two"]
    var tableView = UITableView()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
        self.tableView.delegate      =   self
        self.tableView.dataSource    =   self
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.content.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if cell.detailTextLabel == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.content[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Do any of you know why the tableview is not loading in the view?

Comment: Maybe because table view is empty?

Comment: Confirm the value of `self.view.bounds` in `viewDidLoad`. And don't forget that you need to implement the various table view data source and delegate methods.

Comment: BTW - though probably unrelated to your issue but your `loadView` is unnecessary. Just set the background color in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: Did you set the `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView` to an instance of your controller?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen, Yes. I updated my code

Answer (score 1):

Try and print the size of `self.view.bounds` when you create the table view on `viewDidLoad`, I suspect it will be `.zero`.

I tried this and it works:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    let content = ["One", "Two"]

    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor)
            ])
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return content.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = content[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to register cell to the table view.
Do it after you added the table view.

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for no cells being displayed is that

- you did not register the cell (as @kirander already mentioned)
- your table view has no size at all.

You should not do layout/geometry stuff in `viewDidLoad`, because the frame and bounds are unpredictable at this method's call time.

You either could use autolayout to connect your table view to the dimension of your outer view, or update the frame in `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
    print (self.view.bounds)    // (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
    self.tableView.delegate      =   self
    self.tableView.dataSource    =   self
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print (self.view.bounds)    // (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 668.0)
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

or, when using **autolayout**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
    print (self.view.bounds)    // (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
    self.tableView.delegate      =   self
    self.tableView.dataSource    =   self
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Don't you think that it is more appropriate to change the frame of subviews on `viewWillLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: @Adri Yes, your are completely right. I almost always forget about this... But I would suggest `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `super.loadView()` in `override func loadView()` at the bottom and Appropriate to access the superclass version of the method
for more information on `super` and `LoadView` function,
follow these links [super Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) and [loadView()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview#declarations)